# How to convert letters to numbers with python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary 'g' and I want to convert all letters to numbers.

```
g = { "a" : ["c","e","h","m","k","i"],
      "b" : ["d","f","k","m"]
    }
```

I found this on stack overflow:

```
def alphabet_position_Headcrab(text):
    nums = [str(ord(x) - 96) for x in text.lower() if x >= 'a' and x <= 'z']
    return " ".join(nums)
```

and this one with a prefer:

```
def alphabet_position_wvxvw(text):
    result, i = [32, 32, 32] * len(text), 0
    for c in bytes(text.lower(), 'ascii'):
        if 97 <= c < 106:
            result[i] = c - 48
            i += 2
        elif 106 <= c < 116:
            result[i] = 49
            result[i + 1] = c - 58
            i += 3
        elif 116 <= c <= 122:
            result[i] = 50
            result[i + 1] = c - 68
            i += 3
    return bytes(result[:i-1])
```

But it works not for my dictionary but only for 1Dimensional dictionary like:

```
dic = { "a" : "g", "b" : "f"}
```

Thank you for your help ( perhaps is the answer obvious but I'm not an expert in coding)

Comment: do you want ASCII values for each letter?

Comment: Do you want your numbers to be in a list or returned as a string of numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the functions work for single values, then it should be possible for you to map the function over your list values

```
new_g = {k: [alphabet_position(x) for x in v] for k, v in g.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
for key, value in g.items():
    nums = [str(ord(x) - 96) for x in value if x.lower() >= 'a' and x.lower() <= 'z']
    g[key] = nums
```